# How to make scipy's basinhopping less sensitive in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, simulated-annealing

I am running an optimisation which optimises a function of ~10 paramaters. The function itself takes a reasonably long time (a few seconds) to evaluate and its landscape is very choppy. It can take on values between 0 and 1, with 0 being the theoretical optimum, but I expect the best value is around ~0.01

I am using the [basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html) algorithm to evaluate its minimum, however within each basin the function appears to be optimising for a very small ftol of around 10^-9.

I don't need this level of precision, and instead would like to search the landscape more thoroughly. I would like to adjust the algotihm so that local minima are only optimised to a value of around 10^-4 at best.

I thought this would be a matter of passing some ftol to the minimizer function but I can't seem to get this to work. I am passing this to basinhopping:

```
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "L-BFGS-B","options": {"ftol":1e-2}}
```

but this seems to have no effect and the function is still being evaluated for values with tiny 10^-9 increases in the optimum value.

How can I avoid this? If it really the case that the function cannot be evaluated above this value then I would rather it just output that the value is "0.10" than spending ages evaluating whether it is "0.1000000001" or "0.1000000002"

Comment: Can you share some code?! Otherwise it is difficult to help...

Comment: @Cleb, I'm not sure why code would help, it is a subjective question. Do you mean provide an example of calling the basin hopping algorithm?

Comment: Yes, an example would help, in my opinion.